# In selenium what are the Different use of xpath function (starts-with)?

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

The X-path function **starts-with** in selenium used to handle the dynamic change in the attribute value.

Is there any other scenario where we can use **starts-with** function??

***Thanks in Advance Dudes!!***

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there number of same types of links in your application , and all those having some unique text in their id's like "mpl" here

```
<a id="mpl-123"> link one </a>
<a id="mpl-125"> link two</a>
<a id="mpl-12"> link three </a>
<a id="mpl-183"> link four </a>
<a id="mpl-153"> link five </a>
```

and you wanted to get all those same types of links and iterate through the loop

then you can use `starts-with` function to get all those link in following manner

```
//a[starts-with(@id,'mpl')]
```

Example :

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[starts-with(@id,'mpl')]"));
for(WebElement e:elements)
{
    System.out.println(e.getText());
}
```

Comment: @S.Pethu Raj, If any answer satisfy your need then `accept`that. still have doubt then raise your query

Answer (score 0):

You can use the start-with in xpath to locate an attribute value that starts with a certain text.

For example, assume you have the following link on the page:

```
<a href="mylink_withnumbers">link text</a>
```

Then you can use the following xpath to find links that have an href that starts with 'mylink':

```
//a[starts-with(@href, "mylink")]
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

*HTML*

```
<table class="navFooterVerticalColumn" cellspacing="0" align="center">     
    <tbody>
        <tr> 
            <td class="navFooterLinkCol"> 
                <div class="navFooterColHead">Get to Know Us</div> 
            </td> 
        </tr> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

`starts-with()` can be used not only to *handle the dynamic change in the attribute value*, but also to match element by its text content that starts with some substring:

*XPath*

```
//div[starts-with(text(), "Get to ")]
```

In this case you will match `div` element just by partial text

Also you can use `starts-with()` to match element by partial tag name

*XPath*

```
//*[starts-with(name(), "t")]
```

This will match all the elements which name starts with `"t"`: `table`, `tbody`, `tr`, `td`

Answer (score 0):

Simple. It's handy to use "starts-with" for handling a webelement whose attribute **value changes for every session**.

For eg, consider this html code during session 1,

```
<a id="user347935034"> link one </a>
```

the same webelement in another session say session 2,

```
<a id="user347935035"> link one </a>
```

In this case, if we had wrote xpath without starts with like below, script will fail since the present id value doesn't match with the value existing in the script.

```
//a[@id='user347935034']
```

So, in order to handle those type of webelements we will be using starts-with and ends-with as like below,

```
//a[starts-with(@id,'user')] //user will be a prefix at any session
```

Answer (score 0):

X-path function starts-with can be used for locating element with dynamic attribute values (such as xpath, ex:- suppose element id is like "elemId_1234" and if every time page is refreshed element id changed as "elemId_1234_new"), then you can use starts-with like (//div[starts-with(@id, "elemId_:")]), only thing need to take care to find the **Common data from attribute value**.